# php download page keep getting the same file

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a file downloadable from my site, but the problem is that even that i'm loop over my courses (every course has a file) the same file everytime gets downloaded 
here is my code:

```
<?php
foreach ($courserows AS $courserow) {
    echo "  <tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $courserow['Name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $courserow['Description'] . '</td>';
    ?>
    <td>
        <a href='level-details.php?LId=<?php echo $onecourse['levelid'];?> &download' class='btn btn-success'>
            تحميل <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
    <?php
    echo "</tr>";

    // download file
    if (isset($_GET['download'])) {
        $file = 'material/' . $courserow['file'];
        echo $file;

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the file download code in a separate file.
 But, as per your code, you need to pass file name in anchor tag and receive it using `$_GET`

```
<?php foreach ($courserows AS $courserow){

  echo "  <tr>";
  echo '<td>'.$courserow['Name'].'</td>';

  echo '<td>'.$courserow['Description'].'</td>';



       ?>
       <td>

           <a href='level-details.php?file=<?php echo $onecourse['file'];?>&download' class='btn btn-success'>تحميل   <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>


       </td>
       <?php
       echo "</tr>";

       // download file
       if (isset($_GET['download'])) {
           $file = 'material/' . $_GET['file'];
           echo $file;


           if (file_exists($file)) {
               header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
               header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
               header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
               header('Expires: 0');
               header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
               header('Pragma: public');
               header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
               readfile($file);
               exit;
           }
       }
```

**EDIT:** Also it's better to write the file download code outside the `foreach` loop.

```
// download file
 if (isset($_GET['download'])) {
     $file = 'material/' . $_GET['file'];
     echo $file;


     if (file_exists($file)) {
         header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
         header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
         header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
         header('Expires: 0');
         header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
         header('Pragma: public');
         header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
         readfile($file);
         exit;
     }
 }
foreach ($courserows AS $courserow){

  echo "  <tr>";
  echo '<td>'.$courserow['Name'].'</td>';

  echo '<td>'.$courserow['Description'].'</td>';



       ?>
       <td>

           <a href='level-details.php?file=<?php echo $onecourse['file'];?>&download' class='btn btn-success'>تحميل   <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>


       </td>
       <?php
       echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that actually outputs the file as a download is inside the foreach loop. If the check `if (isset($_GET['download']))` passes, it will do so at the first iteration, and output the file in that iteration. One way to fix this, is to expand the check to something like:

`if (isset($_GET['download']) && $_GET['download'] == $courserow['file'])`